# What is the denial of a statement in logic math?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic, foundations

I'm trying to get the hang of denials in logic in math. I would like to use these two examples:

"Some people are honest and some people are not honest. (All people)"

"No one loves everybody. (All people)"

What would be the denial in both English and logic and why? Thanks.

Comment: Correctly negating natural language sentences is open ended and subjective, because parsing them is subjective. Voting to close.

Comment: @StellaBiderman You're right. I'm assuming converting it into logic and then finding the denial of the logic would be easier?

Comment: Yes certainly, if the sentences are represented in formal logic that would be fine. It would also be fine if you introduced parentheses to the English language sentences to solve scope ambiguity.

Comment: For example "no (one loves everybody)" vs "(no one) loves everybody".

Comment: Any sentence can be negated by appending “It is not the case that” to the beginning.  For example, the negation of “Some people are honest and some people are not honest” is “It is not the case that some people are honest and some people are not honest.”

Comment: Not "denial" but "negation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial point in both formal and natural language is that the negation of a universal statement is an existential statement, and vice versa; specifically, "not everybody" is equivalent to "there exists someone who does not" and "nobody" is equivalent to "everybody does not" although English grammar permits two interpretations of the last expression; I use it to mean "for everybody holds that they do not...".

*While doing the exercises, also keep in mind that the negation of a conjunction is a disjunction and vice versa; e.g., not (A and B) is equivalent to ((not A) or (not B)).*

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand this is by using the existential and universal quantifiers, then understanding the rules of negating those. The existential qualifier $\exists$ is used to say at least one thing exists that fulfills a given statement; the universal quantifier $\forall$ is used to say that *all* things fulfill a given statement. Translating your statements into logic:

> Some people are honest and some people are not honest.

Let $H(x)$ denote that a person $x$ is honest. Then we have $(\exists{x}:H(x)) \wedge (\exists{x}:\neg H(x)) $.

> No one loves everybody.

Let $L(x, y)$ denote that $x$ loves $y$. Then we have $\neg \exists{x} \forall{y}:L(x, y)$. (It is not the case that there exists an $x$ who loves all $y$)

Now for negations, we use the rules that $\neg \forall{x}P(x) \equiv \exists{x} \neg P(x)$ and $\neg \exists{x}P(x) \equiv \forall{x} \neg P(x)$. Negating the first statement, we have

\begin{align}
\neg(\exists{x}:H(x)) \wedge (\exists{x}:\neg H(x)) &\equiv (\neg\exists{x}:H(x)) \vee (\neg\exists{x}:\neg H(x)) &\text{(De Morgan's law)} \\
&\equiv(\forall{x}:\neg H(x)) \vee (\forall{x}:H(x)) &
\end{align}
In plain English,

> either everyone is honest or everyone is not honest

which makes sense as the negation of the original statement.

Negating the second statement is straightforward; $\neg \neg \exists{x} \forall{y}:L(x, y) \equiv \exists{x} \forall{y}:L(x, y)$, meaning

> there exists some person $x$ who loves all people $y$.